# DocumentDb on Azure - I can't get the complete recordset in a single run?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

For an application I created a javascript stored proc to run on AzureDB so I can obtain a set of comprehensive summations, I can then shgow on my screen.

However the count is always off, it seemed as if I never get the full recordset.

So I made a test. I created the following stored proc:

```
function trialRun(startDateTime, endDateTime)
{
    var context = getContext();
    var collection = context.getCollection();
    var response = context.getResponse();

    var sqlString = "select p.id, p.ClientId, p.ActionType, a.Action, a.TimeStamp "
                  + "from History p"
                  + "     join a in p.Actions "
                  + "where a.TimeStamp >= '" + startDateTime + "' "
                  + "  and a.TimeStamp <= '" + endDateTime + "' ";

    // Query documents
    var isAccepted = collection.queryDocuments(collection.getSelfLink(), sqlString,
                                               function (err, feed, options)
                                               {
                                                    if (!err)
                                                    {
                                                        response.setBody(JSON.stringify(feed));
                                                    }
                                                    else
                                                    {
                                                        throw err;
                                                    }
                                               });

    if (!isAccepted) { throw new Error("The query was not accepted by the server."); }
}
```

And indeed, the output misses 10 records.

I read about paging and so... but I haven't found anything relating to this problem so far.

Anyone here who could put me in the right direction? Perhaps a sample code on how to get the data from the next "page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off a recommendation. If all you are doing is a query, you are better off using the client-side SDK and/or [documentdb-utils](https://www.npmjs.com/package/documentdb-utils) (which is just a wrapper for the Azure-provided SDK). Queries inside of a sproc will not use secondaries and limit your overall throughput. Queries from the client SDK will use secondaries and be more performant. If on the other hand, you are aggregating a bunch of rows down to a single result, then a sproc might be best, depending.

That said, even if you move your aggregation into the sproc, you'll have this same problem. So, to fix that, you might want to look at one of the examples in documentdb-utils. Start with the [countDocuments](https://github.com/lmaccherone/documentdb-utils/blob/master/sprocs/countDocuments.coffee) sproc. Also, you might want to learn the pattern for writing restartable sprocs found [here](https://github.com/lmaccherone/documentdb-utils#pattern-for-writing-stored-procedures).

The key concept that I suspect you are missing is that in a NoSQL world and particularly with JavaScript, you need to think asychronously and write your code so that it can be interrupted and restarted.

Assuming that you can move your aggregation needs into the sproc, changes needed to yours as-written include:

1. Don't throw an error when the system stops accepting requests. Rather, save the current state of execution and include an indicator that the sproc needs to be restarted. The countDocuments example I linked to uses `stillQueueing`. If you use documentdb-utils, that will tell it that the sproc wasn't done and needs to be called again.
2. Add a third parameter to your `queryDocuments()` call for `requestOptions` and set `pageSize` in there to 1000. 1000 is big enough that you won't have a ton of round trips to the database, but small enough that you can process it after the system returns a false indicating that it is no longer queueing requests but before the sproc is forcedly timed out.
3. As the pages come in do your aggregation, accumulating the result in the body that you'll return.
4. You do not need to `JSON.stringify()` the response. They system will take care of marshaling plain JavaScript Objects.
5. In any case, don't stick the entire feed in your response. Only your aggregation.
6. Capture the continuation token found in the third `options` parameter of the callback and pass that back with your response.

If you really want to use a sproc and return all rows rather than the client SDK or a sproc with just aggregation, then I need to warn you off of using documentdb-utils. If you stick the entire feed in the response, it will try to send it back and forth for each round trip and quickly exceed the maximum payload for a sproc call or return. You could use the raw SDK though and just make sure to strip the feed contents out before going back for another call.

Comment: Well, it was just a quick test. I wanted to see what the records where my stored proc was looping through.

Comment: In my actual stored proc, I'm looping through the feed and creating a couple of dictionary objects; those are the objects I stringify and then send to the client again.

Comment: I suspected that you might actually want to build an aggregation. :-) Even so, you don't need to stringify them. Just return the JavaScript objects. The thing that's missing is some way to go back for more pages.

Comment: You don't happen to have an example in pure javascript? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've done a combination of your answer and the sample stored proc I found on [GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-js-server/blob/master/samples/stored-procedures/Count.js)

Using these 2 as references I reworked my 'trial stored proc like this:

```
function trialRun(startDateTime, endDateTime, continuationToken)
{
    var context = getContext();
    var collection = context.getCollection();
    var maxResult = 1000;   // Value from sample = 25

    var sqlString = "select p.id, p.ClientId, p.ActionType, a.Action, a.TimeStamp "
                   + "from History p"
                   + "     join a in p.Actions "
                   + "where a.TimeStamp >= '" + startDateTime + "' "
                   + "  and a.TimeStamp <= '" + endDateTime + "' ";
    var result = null;

    tryQuery(continuationToken, sqlString);

    // Helper method to check for max result and call query.
    function tryQuery(nextContinuationToken)
    {
        var responseOptions = { continuation: nextContinuationToken, pageSize : maxResult };

        // In case the server is running this script for long time/near timeout, it would return false,
        // in this case we set the response to current continuation token, 
        // and the client will run this script again starting from this continuation.
        // When the client calls this script 1st time, is passes empty continuation token.
        if (result >= maxResult || !query(responseOptions)) { setBody(nextContinuationToken); }
    }

    function query(responseOptions)
    {
        var resultSet = collection.queryDocuments(collection.getSelfLink(), sqlString, responseOptions, onReadDocuments);

        return resultSet;
    }

    function onReadDocuments(err, docFeed, responseOptions)
    {
        if (err)
        {
            throw 'Error while reading document: ' + err;
        }

        // Increament the number of documents counted so far.
        result += JSON.Stringify(docFeed);

        // If there is continuation, call query again with it, 
        // otherwise we are done, in which case set continuation to null.
        if (responseOptions.continuation)
        {
            tryQuery(responseOptions.continuation);
        }
        else
        {
            setBody(null);
        }
    }

    // Set response body: use an object the client is expecting (2 properties: result and continuationToken).
    function setBody(continuationToken)
    {
        var body = { trialRun: result, continuationToken: continuationToken };
        getContext().getResponse().setBody(body);
    }
}
```

Now the result set I receive contains the missing 10 records. I'll rework my actual procedure in the same manner.

Comment: I know, I'm stil using a `JSON.stringify` call here. But I'm not yet clear how I can "add" the newly created object data to the already existing result set.

Comment: You can concatenate the array you previously created with each additional page.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by dictionary but if you mean a JavaScript object, you can add new elements with a loop.